# Is History of Chassidus part of Jewish Life and Learning?

Tags: discussion, scope

Is History of Chassidus part of  Jewish Life and Learning or is it too specific?

Answer (score 6):

It depends on the scope of the question. If your question is something like:

- [What to call the 7th Lubavitcher Rebbe](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/5052/what-to-call-the-7th-lubavitcher-rebbe)
- [What is the typical retirement plan for a Chabad-Lubavitch shliach (emissary)?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8373/what-is-the-typical-retirement-plan-for-a-chabad-lubavitch-shliach-emissary)
- [Do Chasidim avoid wearing ties?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/4165/do-chasidim-avoid-wearing-ties)

then it seems within scope. If your question is something like: "What are all of the concepts put forth by the Chassidim which the Misngadim found wrong, and what did the Misnagdim do what the Chassidim thought wrong, and what did they respond to each other", well, one can write a book about that.

Comment: Is that agreed upon by all?

Comment: There are 34 questions tagged [Chassidus](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chasidut-hasidism). I don't see why they should be off scope (they are a large portion of Jews). Should Yemenite customs also be off scope?

Comment: right but the history ofchassidus is more so

Comment: @simchashatorah is "history of Yemenites" of topic?